# What happens if you try to perform an operation on a locked part of a MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, locking

I am using the Node.js driver for MongoDB.

I understand that if I drop a collection during the operation the database will be write locked.

If I try to perform another write operation on the database while it is locked what will happen? Will that operation return an error or will MongoDB automatically wait for the lock to be lifted and retry?

If an error is returned what is the error code and error message it will return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB will keep your query in waiting and execute after the lock is removed. if you are deleting a collection and at the same time you try and write to the same collection first it will delete the collection and then once the lock is removed it will create a new collection with new document.
you can find more information over [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use)